# EAS updates not working possibly due to missing channel-name in Expo.plist

Tags: react-native, expo, eas, expo-updates

I'm trying to make EAS updates to work, after debugging,  the issue seems to be the missing channel-name, which does not appear in Expo.plist, although,I believe, my eas.json is set up correctly.

I am not using anywhere in the app releaseChannel, replaced it with channel and I did rebuilt the app. Did anyone encounter this issue or knows a solution ? This is how I set the profile in eas.json:

```
“build”:{
 "staging-1863": {
      "channel": "staging-1863",
      "env": {
        "ENVIRONMENT": "staging"
      },
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk",
        "credentialsSource": "local"
      },
      "ios": {
        "credentialsSource": "local"
      }
    },
}
```

Comment: I got the same issue. It happens only for android.